# Loop JSON objects in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to figure out how to display custom HTML objects created by users. For example, the user can create custom styled button(s) with the following properties: `color`, `font-size`, and `border-radius`. Here is an example of my `json`:

```
    [
      {
        id: 2,
        configs: {
          color: "#000000",
          font_size: 10,
          border_radius: 0,
          display: true,
          button_1: [
            {
              color: "red",
              font_size: 12,
              border_radius: 4,
              display: true,
            }
          ],
        },
        created_at: "2020-05-07T21:42:04.808Z",
        updated_at: "2020-05-07T21:42:04.808Z",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        configs: {
        color: "#000000",
        font_size: 10,
        border_radius: 0,
        display: true,
        button_1: [
          {
            color: "blue",
            font_size: 15,
            border_radius: 24,
          }
        ],
        button_2: [
          {
            color: "pink",
            border_radius: 2,
          }
        ],
      },
      created_at: "2020-05-07T22:29:31.255Z",
      updated_at: "2020-05-07T22:29:31.255Z",
    },
  ]
```

I want to display all buttons according to the user's style settings. Tried something like:

```
%p #{btn.id}: #{btn[:configs][:button_1][0][:color][:font_size]}
```

But it doesn't look practical. Besides, in certain cases it can lead to the error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I've tried to use gem like [activerecord-typedstore](https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore) but it seems like it doesn't support nested attributes ([Is there a way to master a nested json with a json column?](https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore/issues/76)). Is there any way to display custom button(s) based on the user's criteria?

Comment: Hint: JSON uses string keys. You can load in with symbols if you prefer, but you must ask.

Comment: @tadman thank you for the hint. Can you give more information about symbols, please? I've done tons of research but it seems like I still don't understand JSON objects

Comment: Too loop through the json structure use `.dig()` as recommended in the answer (your object needs to be an Array or Hash), and if you intend to display the button as an html element and not only it's data, you can use content_tag https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby `"configs"` and `:configs` are not equivalent. You must use the type employed in the structure.

To navigate complex JSON structures use [`dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
btn.dig('configs', 'button_1', 0, 'color', 'font_size')
```

You can also symbolize the keys if you want using `symbolize_keys`:

```
btn.symbolize_keys!
```

If you prefer symbols and you're reading in the JSON manually you can always request it with symbol keys out of the gate using the [symbolize_names](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/JSON.html#method-i-parse) option to `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse('{"test": true}')
# => {"test"=>true}
JSON.parse('{"test": true}', symbolize_names: true)
# => {:test=>true}
```

Comment: I am getting  `undefined method `dig'   error. Anyways, thank you very much for the help and time, will do more research about `dig`

Comment: You may be using a version of Ruby < 2.5, in which case an update will help. You can always do this the hard way with `btn['configs']['button_1'][0]...`

Comment: I am using Ruby `2.7.1`. Thank you again, you saved me tons time.

Comment: That should be available on Hash and Array, so if you have more problems with it worth posting another question directed to that specifically.